# Order of coordinate subjects including 'I'

Tags: pronouns, subjects

Why is:

> "I and Daniel are taking him to the park"

wrong, but

> "Daniel and I are taking him to the park"

isn't.

*I* and *Daniel*, no matter what the order, are both part of the subject (and *him* the object), so why does it matter what order the subject is in?

Comment: What do you mean by "talking him to the park"? Do you mean "**taking** him to the park"?

Answer (score 0):

It's not grammatically wrong. It's considered more *polite* to put yourself second.

However, you should consider sentences like

> I and Daniel made a lot of mistakes on this project

to be exceptions to this rule. Here, it's probably more polite to put yourself first.

Comment: Thank you! But why is *I and Daniel made a lot of mistakes on this project* more polite to say this than in *I and Daniel are talking him to the park*? Both are doing the verb..so whether it's more polite to put oneself first should be irrelevant because A and B did this, does not mean just because A is first, A is responsible.

Comment: If it's about making *mistakes* then putting *I* first places the emphasis on yourself—you take more blame. It's the same reason that law some firms, named after partners, put the most "important" name first. It's a social convention, not one of English per se.